# Creating download queue of images

Tags: ios, download, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I want to create method in that coming images and all of them downloading in queue one by one. I use AFNetworking 2.0. I want to know is there any pre-created code that can help me in my question ?

My code

```
    NSString *urlString = link;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        UIImage *image = responseObject;
        //here I seve image to disk and so on
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        DDLogError(@"FAIL download image: %@",error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with dispatch_group: all downloads are group into one queue and are downloaded one by one

[AFNetworking 2.0 download multiple images with completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671720/afnetworking-2-0-download-multiple-images-with-completion/23671946#23671946)