# App is crashing when loading multiple images from server using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have integrated the AFNetworking library in my app to download images from a URL and the app is crashing when we are loading multiple images.

When I analyse my code using the Xcode crash report list (Xcode -> Window -> Organizer -> Crashes -> Our app), it is showing an error in the AFNetworking library for this line of code:

> **Class**: `UIImageView+AFNetworking`
>
> **Method Name**: `setImageWithURLRequest`
>
> **Line of code**: `[[[self class] af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue] addOperation:self.af_imageRequestOperation];`

Can anyone help me sort out this problem?

Comment: What's the actual error? And update your question with relevant code.

Comment: When I am adding same operation to sharedImageRequestOperationQueue of AFNetworking, it is throwing an error like

 "-[UIImageView(AFNetworking) setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:]_block_invoke89 + 120"

Comment: That's not an error message. That's part of the stack trace. The crash log will also have an actual error message.

Comment: I will upload stack trace screenshot if you want but I am not able to see crash logs here.

Comment: You should better update the library. The method you're using is deprecated and the updated one is something like sd_setImageWithURL. Hopefully it'll solve the problem.

Comment: Try this , hope this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26406937/5649323

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YourImageURL"];

 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];

 __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = yourImageView;

 [weakImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request

                      placeholderImage:placeholderImage

                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                       weakImageView.image = image;

                                   } failure:nil];
```

Comment: you can also use NSCache with this code. this will reduce loading of same image again and again.

Answer (score 1):

There are many unit tests around image downloading, and a brand new architecture in the 3.0.0 branch with additional tests covering multiple images being downloading.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire  install this pod

Try the following code for uploading multiple images to the server
 code:

```
 Alamofire.upload(
            .POST,
            urlString,
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                for image in images {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1) {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    }
                }
            },
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in    
                        if response.result.error != nil {
                            print("Something is wrong while uploading images.")
                        } else {
                        }
                    })
                case .Failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: Use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage      for images dowloading use this sample code cell.ImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: car.mediaList[0].url ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "testCar"))